# Vertical lines in table only appear on first and last row

Tags: tables

Creating a table in LaTex and want the columns separated by a vertical line.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{TestTable}
    \begin{tabular}{c | c}
    Sample & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Data} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{123123} & 12312 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{234234} & 324534 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{4534} & 324234 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{23423} & 345345 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{345345} & 32423 \\
    ter23423 & 4562 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Only getting a vertical line on the first and last row. Why is this? I'm using : `begin{tabular}{c | c}` 
[image]

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{1}{r|}{...}`

Comment: Why not use `\begin{tabular{r|c}` and a single `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` in the column header?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the column specifiers to `{r|c}` you will only need a single `multicolumn` command for the word Sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{TestTable}
    \begin{tabular}{r|c}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Sample} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Data} \\
    \hline
    123123 & 12312 \\
    234234 & 324534 \\
    4534 & 324234 \\
    23423 & 345345 \\
    345345 & 32423 \\
    ter23423 & 4562 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that the last row of the table should be centered, too

Comment: @CarLaTeX: You re right. I have not added a second `\multicolumn` command for the entry in the last row as it does not make any difference if the widest entry of a table column is centered or right aligned. The output will look the same. A difference will only be visible if an even wider entry is added.

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference, in this case, I told you only because the OP's MWE is so